# Locate Specific Value in Column Range and Transpose Adjacent Matching Rows into Columns

Tags: excel-formula, reference, transpose

Find Specific Value in Column Range and Transpose Adjacent Matching Rows into Columns

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula in Office 365:

```
 =TRANSPOSE(FILTER(L1:O6,H1:H6=1,""))
```

[image]

If not then highlight four cells in a column and put this in the formula bar:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(L1:O6,MATCH(1,$H$1:$H$6,0),0))
```

And confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter to array enter the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thank you... Thank you so very much.  Your formula works like a charm, I really appreciate your help and feedback.